# Combining expressions and text together in PlotLegends Mathematica

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a code which goes like this:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"This is for x", "This is for 2x", "This is for 3x"}]
```

which produces the plots:

[image]

I need to write legends in such a way that it takes, say, 1st expression and then besides that it writes "This is for x" (same for 2nd and 3rd). How can we do this in Mathematica?

I tried with this code (not sure why !):

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Expressions", {"This is for x", "This is for 2x", 
    "This is for 3x"}}]
```

But, I am getting another set of legend down the figure:
[image]

How can one accomplish this?

Mathematica version: 12.1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
plot  = Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"];
```

You can post-process the output to replace legend labels with the desired strings:

```
plot /. HoldPattern[p : HoldForm[_[a_]]] :> Row[{p, " -- This is for ", HoldForm @a}]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
With[{ri = RandomInteger[{3, 7}]}, 
  Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[ri x + x^2], Sin[ri x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]] /. 
 HoldPattern[p : HoldForm[_[a_]]] :> Row[{p, " -- This is for ", HoldForm @ a}]
```

[image]